# cross-origin request blocked in angular js parse post request for user table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, parse-platform

I am getting below error on submitting a POST request to parse user table.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.parse.com/classes/1/user. (Reason: CORS request failed).

Can anyone help to identify the problem with my code. I am trying to insert a sample user details into user table in parse.com

```
 $scope.updateUser = function() {       
    var userData={
            "username":"test12",
            "password":"test12"
    };

    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(userData);



      $http({method:'POST', url: 'https://api.parse.com/classes/1/user',data:jsonData,
          headers: {
                'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'Lh9k1RqrWKsaiKtB9zDlFulBiIshATJU6CpKit49',
                'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': 'qEwJ0ImBv4ARDostCnKBlUQPwTJuRk5wjtPUUxFr',
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
               'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',
               'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
              }  
      }).
        then(function(response) {
            console.log('success');
          $scope.status = response.status;
          $scope.data = response.data;
        }, function(response) {
          $scope.data = response.data || "Request failed";
          $scope.status = response.status;
      });
    };
```

Comment: The REST API that you're calling (https://api.parse.com/classes/1/user) should send `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers in the response. Only then the browser will accept and pass on the response to your callbacks. Setting `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers in the request will not help.

Comment: Do you know how to send Access-Control-Allow-* headers in the response from parse.com?

Comment: Whats your server "parse.com" coded upon?

Comment: Do you know for sure if your Parse API allows Cross Origin requests ?

Answer (score 0):

```
put this tags in Web.config. it works for me.

<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```